# base64 to file response not working

Tags: java, jsp

Due to development restrictions we are sending all the data in base64 from client to server, also the uploaded files (pdf or txt files). Those files are being correctly stored in mysql database as LONGBLOB after this procedures in java:

```
decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(request.getParameter("fic_adjunto"));
ficheroAdjunto = new SerialBlob(decodedBytes);
```

But when I want to download some file from jsp, I'm using this servlet code with an html link:

jsp-file:

```
<a href='GestionDescargas?valor=LoadFile&IdEvent=26'>
```

Server-side:

Conexion oConexion = new Conexion();

```
            Evento oEvento = new Evento();
            oEvento = oConexion.RecuperaEventoByIdEvento(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("IdEvent")));

            response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + oEvento.getNomFicheroAdjunto());

            Blob fileBlob = oEvento.getFicheroAdjunto();
            int blobLength = (int) fileBlob.length();  
            byte[] blobAsBytes = fileBlob.getBytes(1, blobLength); 
            String base64String = Base64.encodeBase64String(blobAsBytes);

            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64String.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            int read=0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[BYTES_DOWNLOAD];
            OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();

            while((read = is.read(bytes))!= -1)
            {
                os.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

Im quite new in this programming world, could you give me a hand please?. I have tried everything but only getting the base64 string (and is not even equal to the original but almost)

Original base64 string:

```
data:text/plain;base64,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
```

Decoded from database string:

```
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
```

What I want is to get the original file anyway... and not the base64 string.

Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: it is rather astonishing that the decoded string is really really similar except for the colons : and the semicolons and commas ; , becoming forward slashes / ... and the very end of it is changed.  Diego Maye mentions ensuring that the string is in UTF-8 on both sides of the transaction, so definitely try that!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is related to the way that you are using to send the file, for example if the file is encoded with iso-8859-1, you need to do the next (because you read the BLOB with UTF-8):

```
decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
decodedBytes = decoder.decodeBuffer(new String(request.getParameter("fic_adjunto").getBytes("iso-8859-1"), "UTF-8"));
ficheroAdjunto = new SerialBlob(decodedBytes);
```

The code above will be useful only if you are sending the file in iso-8859-1 format, to avoid this (re-format the String) you need to force the request to send in UTF-8 format.